# How to extract leaf certificates from PKCS #7 files

Tags: openssl, certificate, code-signing

I have extracted some certificates from windows executable files encoded in DER format and then convert it to readable format using this openssl command:

```
# openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -print_certs -text -in cert.der
```

The output file consist of several certificates. How can I filter out all the certificates except the leaf one. I don't need for example intermediate or TSA ones.

For example this is one of the extracted certificates:

[[1]: https://pastebin.com/ij2h8i63](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://pastebin.com/ij2h8i63)

Comment: Hi, Just curious if you've found a way to extract the leaf certificate using openssl ? thanks

Comment: @Zohar81: Hey, No! and still am interested to find a way for doing that!

Answer (score 0):

Once you got PKCS#7 block, you can get the leaf certificate using openssl C++ interface by extracting the list of certificates in chain and accessing the first certificate in index 0 (It might also have an equivalent in command line)

In the following code `Pkcs7` defined as a pointer to PKCS7 structure.

```
BIO *out = BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
int i = OBJ_obj2nid(Pkcs7->type);
if(i == NID_pkcs7_signed) {
    certs = Pkcs7 ->d.sign->cert;
} else if(i == NID_pkcs7_signedAndEnveloped) {
    certs = Pkcs7->d.signed_and_enveloped->cert;
}


os_log_info(g_logger, "number of ceritifcates = %d", sk_X509_num(certs));
X509 *rootCertX509 = sk_X509_value(certs,sk_X509_num(certs)-1);
X509 *leafCertX509 = sk_X509_value(certs,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you stumbled here because the certs extracted are from a PDF ( could be from a PE as in your case) ( https://superuser.com/questions/1242743/inspecting-digital-signature-in-pdf-file ) , then a nice little awk oneliner can write the separate certs in separate files. Inspecting them one by one to do the filtering you want should be easier now

```
pdfsig somepdf.pdf -dump
openssl pkcs7 -inform der -text  -print_certs -in somepdf.sig0 | awk 'BEGIN {i=0} /Subject:/ {i+=1;d=sprintf("cert-%d.pem",i);} /----BEGIN/,/END CERTIFICATE-----/ {print $0 >> d}'
```